# Sort columns and rows by ID of place name in a crosstab query

Tags: ms-access

I have a crosstab query which works pretty well except its showing the columns alphabetically instead of a different order.

I have a grid of pricing of origin to destination train stations which I previously had in the right order when the rows and columns were showing the station_id rather than the station name.

The stations have a station_id which are chronological. These station IDs are associated to a station_from and a station_to number field and the query does a lookup of the station name for both from and to.

When it runs, all the columns and rows are in alphabetical order by the station_name, I want it to be in the order (both columns and rows) by the station_id instead. Any ideas? I'm doing this in MS Access from Office 365.

Here's the query I have (thanks to @kenwhite for helping me with that) which takes a table which maps a route between stations and a price zone.

```
TRANSFORM Max(r.price) AS MaxOfprice
SELECT o.[Station Name]
 FROM ([zone_pricing Query] AS r 
   INNER JOIN stations AS o ON r.station_from = o.station_ID) 
   INNER JOIN stations AS d ON r.station_to = d.station_ID
 WHERE (((r.ticket_type)='adult') AND ((r.season_ID)=1))
GROUP BY o.[Station Name], r.season_ID, r.ticket_type
PIVOT d.[Station Name];
```

**zone_pricing Query** looks like this:

```
station_from,   station_to, zone_id,    price,  price_type, price_class,    season_ID,  ticket_type,    route_id

1   2   1   $58.00  base    flexi   1   adult   1

1   3   1   $58.00  base    flexi   1   adult   1

2   3   1   $58.00  base    flexi   1   adult   1

1   4   1   $58.00  base    flexi   1   adult   1

2   4   1   $58.00  base    flexi   1   adult   1

3   4   1   $58.00  base    flexi   1   adult   1

22  4   1   $58.00  base    flexi   1   adult   1

1   5   2   $83.00  base    flexi   1   adult   1

2   5   2   $83.00  base    flexi   1   adult   1

3   5   2   $83.00  base    flexi   1   adult   1

22  5   2   $83.00  base    flexi   1   adult   1
```

I have **stations** that look like this:

```
Station_ID, Location,   Station Name,   Scheduled Stop, Short Platform, Station Type,   station_code

1   Auckland    Auckland Strand Yes No  Rail    AKL

2       Middlemore  No  No  Rail    MDM

3       Papakura    Yes No  Rail    PAP

4       Hamilton    Yes No  Rail    HLR

5       Te Awamutu  No  Yes Rail    TWM

6       Otorohanga  Yes Yes Rail    OTO

7       Te Kuiti    No  Yes Rail    TEK

8       Taumarunui  No  No  Rail    TAU
```

Comment: under stations, you'll notice Location doesn't exist in any other than the top record, remove location entirely, you don't need it for what I'm doing, all those values are the station name. Remove the first word Auckland, not required. Thanks

Comment: You can edit your question to correct that.

Comment: Look at [online docs for the TRANSFORM statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/transform-statement-microsoft-access-sql).  You can include an explicit list of column names in a particular order using the `IN` keyword of the `PIVOT` clause.  That will allow you to manually specify the column order, but it removes all dynamic behavior.  That will end up excluding any columns that are not in the list and it will fill missing column data with nulls.

Comment: How many stations? If too many for IN(), can concatenate Station_ID with Station Name and pivot on that constructed field.

Comment: Sorry for a sloppy "answer", but don't have time now for specific solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261090/how-to-call-vba-function-for-specifying-columns-in-sql-transform-query/44166251#44166251 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898593/transform-multiple-rows-into-columns-with-unique-key/45900941#45900941 for advanced techniques on manipulating crosstab columns. *But it looks like the only static way to order columns is to either us the IN clause or a subsequent query which re-orders the columns.*  **The best option may be VBA which dynamically produces the query.**

Comment: maximum 22 but usually much less - it's a rail network with considerably less apart from nonscheduled stops

Comment: thank you for your answers, I'll check them out